# Find value of parameter such that the maximum value of a function satisfies a condition

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have defined a function `x3` as follows:

```
F0 = 31.6*1000 (*N*);
t1 = 0.0109 (*s*);
 m = 4200(*kg*);    
force[τ_] := 
     Piecewise[{
       {F0 τ/(t1/2), 0 <= τ < t1/2}, 
       {2 F0 (1 - τ/t1), t1/2 <= τ < t1}, 
       {0, t1 <= τ}}
     ]

x3[t_, k_]:= 
     Integrate[1/m force[τ] 1/Sqrt[k/m] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] (t - τ)], {τ,0, t1/2}, 
       Assumptions -> t1 ∈ Reals ] + 
     Integrate[1/m force[τ] 1/Sqrt[k/m] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] (t - τ)], {τ,t1/2, t1}, 
       Assumptions -> t1 ∈ Reals] + 
     Integrate[1/m force[τ] 1/Sqrt[k/m] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] (t - τ)], {τ, t1, t}, 
       Assumptions -> {t > t1, k > 0}]
```

Now I have to find the minimum value of the parameter $k$ such that the maximum value of `x3[t, k]` is less than $0.001$. I would personally also like to see a plot of the function, but I can't get that far.

I tried the following code:

```
NSolve[FindMaximum[x3[t, k], t] <= 0.001, k]
```

where my idea was to find the maximum value of `x3` for arbitrary $t$. Yet this doesn't work as I imagined (actually it doesn't work at all!).

Comment: `force` is not defined. You mention the variable `F0` but it is not used. Can you update the question.

Comment: @JackLaVigne yes, my mistake! The example above should be complete now.

Comment: Skrat, as mentioned in the answer to your other question, you probably should also define `x3` using `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`), so you don't recalculate the integral every time `x3` is evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, using the rest of your definitions, redefine `x3` using `Set` so that it doesn't recompute the integral for each evaluation:

```
Clear[x3]
x3[t_, k_] = Simplify[
  Integrate[1/m force[τ] 1/Sqrt[k/m] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] (t - τ)], {τ, 0, t1/2}, Assumptions -> t1 ∈ Reals] + 
  Integrate[1/m force[τ] 1/Sqrt[k/m] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] (t - τ)], {τ, t1/2, t1}, Assumptions -> t1 ∈ Reals] + 
  Integrate[1/m force[τ] 1/Sqrt[k/m] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] (t - τ)], {τ, t1, t}, Assumptions -> {t > t1, k > 0}]
]

(*Out: 
(1/(k^(3/2)))(-3.75764*10^8 Sin[0.0154303 Sqrt[k] (-0.0109 + t)] + 
 7.51528*10^8 Sin[0.0154303 Sqrt[k] (-0.00545 + t)] - 
 3.75764*10^8 Sin[0.0154303 Sqrt[k] t])
*)
```

Let's plot `x3` for a few values of `k`, randomly chosen:

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[
    Tooltip[x3[t, k], k],
    {k, PowerRange[1, 1000, 2]}
  ],
 {t, 0, 50},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> ("k = " <> ToString@# & /@ PowerRange[1, 1000, 2])
]
```

[image: plots for some values of k]

It is clear from the plot, if not from the expression for `x3`, that the higher the value of $k$, the smaller the period of the function, and the lower the maximum amplitude.

Some more exploration using the plotting expression shown above and adjusting parameters by hand indicates that the minimum $k$ value for which `x3[t, k]` has a maximum under $0.001$ is close to 6,000,000.

[image: more exploration]

Now that we have a good starting point, we can use `FindRoot` to obtain a more accurate result:

```
Clear[nmax]
nmax[k_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[x3[t, k], t]
FindRoot[nmax[k] == 0.001, {k, 6000000}]

(* Out: {k -> 7.00376*10^6} *)
```

---

**Update for damped oscillation:**

As you mentioned in comments, you are now interested in:

```
x3[t_, k_] = Simplify[
  Integrate[
    F0/(t1/
        2) 1/(m ω0D) Exp[-δ ω0D (t - τ)] τ Sin[ω0D (t - τ)], {τ, 0, t1/2}
  ] +
   Integrate[
    2 F0 (1 - τ/
        t1) 1/(m ω0D) Exp[-δ ω0D (t - τ)] Sin[ω0D (t - τ)], {τ, t1/2, t1}
   ]
 ]
```

This expression also leads to a closed-form integral, so the method outlined above should work as well.

Again, let's identify a reasonable range for our search using plotting:

```
Plot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[Tooltip[x3[t, k], k], {k, PowerRange[1000000, 10000000, 2]}],
  {t, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends ->
   ("k = " <> ToString@# & /@ PowerRange[1000000, 10000000, 2])
]
```

[image: damped oscillation exploration]

$k=4\times10^6$ looks like a good starting point for the search. Using the same `FindRoot` code, however, leads to many complaints, although it does return a somewhat reasonable result:

[image: failed FindRoot]

The difficulty is in `NMaxValue` though, not in `FindRoot`. However, since we know roughly from the plot in what range of $t$ the maximum is to be found ($0.04 \leq t \leq 0.07$)), let's help out `NMaxValue` by providing a constraint on $t$:

```
Clear[nmaxConstrained]
nmaxConstrained[k_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[{x3[t, k], 0.04 < t < 0.07}, t]
FindRoot[nmaxConstrained[k] == 1/1000, {k, 4000000}]

(* Out: {k -> 3.79798*10^6} *)
```

... and no more complaints from `NMaxValue`.

Comment: I really like you calling `k={1, 2, 4, 8, 16,... 512}` randomly chosen...

Comment: @BlacKow Hehe... I guess I meant that I didn't know if $k$ should be very small or very large to fulfill the requirement, so I "randomly" chose to start with very large values and got lucky. Also, [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/) :-)

Comment: A very nice idea using `nmax[k_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[x3[t, k], t]`. Thank you. This answers my question completely.

Comment: @MarcoB: I tried to use your solution in case of damped oscillations, where `x3[t_, k_] = 
  Simplify[(Integrate[
      F0 /(t1/2) 1/(m ω0D)
         Exp[-δ ω0D (t - τ)] τ Sin[ω0D \
(t - τ)], {τ, 0, t1/2}] + 
     Integrate[
      2 F0 (1 - τ/t1) 1/(m ω0D)
         Exp[-δ ω0D (t - τ)] Sin[ω0D (t - \
τ)], {τ, t1/2, t1}])];` and `\[Omega]0D = Sqrt[k/m] Sqrt[1 - \[Delta]^2];` but `FindRoot` from your answer gives me an error saying that the function may be unbounded. Do you have an idea what could be the problem and how to pass it?

Comment: Assuming $\delta =0.23$

Comment: @skrat I've updated my answer to address your damped oscillation issue.